# Any points to use else in file lock?

Tags: php, file-locking

Have seen several script example with php file writing where they lock the file with an if statement. I have not found any examples of what I should write in else. I use this to create simple txt log files and do not want to print anything to the user if it fails. Can I skip the if/else or what should I have in the else?

```
$fh = fopen($logFile, 'w');
if (flock($fh, LOCK_EX)) {
    foreach($datecounts as $datecount)
    {
        fwrite($fh, $datecount.PHP_EOL);
    }
    flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
}
else
{
    //couldn't lock.
}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: If it returns `false` it may already be locked and you may want to take corrective actions or bail out. So it really depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

of course, you can skip it. But you can also use it for debug purposes (like logging in case of errors)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to do anything just close it .

```
 flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
```

so that when you try next time it will not create issue for you .

Answer (score 0):

> do not want to print anything to the user if it fails...

So what *do* you want to do if it fails?

Or to put it another way, what are the implications of failure?

It looks like you're writing a log file, and if it can't lock the file you just want to silently fail. That means you won't get a log, nor any indication that logging isn't happening.

If logging is important to you then this isn't great. But if you're happy with that situation, then you're right; there's no need for the `else` clause.

But you should also consider what a failure to lock the file means. It could mean that you have a problem with file permissions or that someone else has it open, or maybe that the disk is full or even a disk error. You may not care that the log file doesn't get written, but any of these problems could lead to a worse situation later in your program, and reporting it early could save you from that.